# Jasper report sum of each group item

Tags: sum, jasper-reports, each

I am using Jasper Report 4.5
My problem is I have list of employees and its monthly tax deduction.
I need the report in which it shows employees tax deduction group by monthly
and in bottom it should display total(sum of) tax deduction of each employee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it.

1. Order the resultset by month, then by employee.
2. Create level 1 report group, group1, which groups by month and a level 2 group, group2, that groups by employee.
3. Create a sum variable that resets on group1.
4. Print the sum in the trailer of group2.

Answer (score 0):

If in your detail section you have records for multiple employees/dates and then you want a total for each employee at the bottom, I think the best solution would be to use a sub report.

You could create a sub report that shows the totals for each employee.  You could pass any parameters you need from the main report to the sub report.  You could put the sub report in the Summary section (or possibly a group footer) of your report.